# What does context information means when talking about Overlapped I/O?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, iocp, overlapped-io

In the documentation for [`WSARecv()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it says:

> If lpCompletionRoutine is not NULL, the hEvent parameter is ignored
>   and can be used by the application to pass context information to the
>   completion routine.

What does "context information" means? I think it means that I will usually associate a data structure with each socket, which can contain members such as the socket handle and the receive buffer. And so when I call `WSARecv()` I will pass to it a pointer to an instance of this data structure, and when I get notified that a receive operation has completed, I will get the pointer I passed earlier, and so I will know which socket has initiated the receive operation, and what is the receive buffer, etc.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's basically correct. The context is an application-defined piece of information (usually a pointer to a custom structure) that can be used by the callback to perform its operation. You will find this scheme throughout the Windows API, e.g. the `lpParam` parameter in a call to [CreateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx). This, too, can be used by an application to transfer additional information to a recipient.

Answer (score 1):

> What does "context information" means?

User-defined data.  When the IOCP ignores that field, you can use it to pass whatever custom (context-sensitive) data you want to the completion routine.

Comment: But it's not type-safe.  A better option is to add fields after the `OVERLAPPED` structure, since you get back the same `OVERLAPPED*` you pass in.

Comment: And you don't think that is any less type-safe? An IOCP operation only takes an `OVERLAPPED*` as input, and gives you back an `OVERLAPPED*` as output.  You still have to type-cast to access the extra fields you add. Whether you pass a pointer via `hEvent`, or pass a pointer via `OVERLAPED*`, it is the same thing one way or the other - the pointer gets passed as-is to the completion routine, and you use it as needed. Extending `OVERLAPPED` is the common approach, but it is not the only approach.

Comment: Or use the `OVERLAPPED*` as a key (e.g. `std::map`)

Comment: @Ben: Neither option adds type-safety. Whichever one you choose, both sender and consumer have to agree on the same type. The compiler cannot help you there. Even if you use the `OVERLAPPED*` as a key into an associative container, both parties will have to agree on that as well.

Comment: @IInspectable: The sender (remote peer) has no influence over any of this.  Yes, the `WSARecv` caller and callback have to agree, but the callback is under the control of the caller, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @Ben: I was addressing your comments *"But it's not type-safe. A better option is [...] Or use [...]"* Neither of these options adds type-safety. Of course, making producer and consumer agree on a type is trivial. If you do get it wrong, the compiler's type checking will not spot the error, though.

Comment: Neither one is perfect but I think a downcast with static_cast is "better" than using reinterpret_cast between unrelated types. And for more safety the associative container can be used.

Comment: @Ben: How is `static_cast`ing to the wrong type any better than `reinterpret_cast`ing to the wrong type? If you get it wrong, stuff breaks. And no compiler to warn you. Overloading a type to add the property of being a key is also purely conventional, and cannot be expressed in C or C++. You provided alternatives, that can be useful in specific scenarios. None of the alternatives are inherently better, let alone more type-safe.

Comment: @IInspectable: For `static_cast`, it is true that the compiler won't check that the dynamic type of the object is correct, but it will verify that an inheritance relationship actually exists.  That's better already.  And the associative container is 100% type-safe, requiring no casting whatsoever (perhaps internally, such as during hashing if you use `unordered_map`, but that is not your responsibility to get right).

Comment: @Ben: Whether the types are related or not is of **zero** relevance. If producer and consumer do not agree, you have a problem, and no compiler to warn you. There is no "better" way to get something wrong. While an associative container is type-safe, you ignored step 1: Deducing that some piece of information is used as the key. Again, this is purely conventional, and cannot be expressed in C or C++. So no help from the compiler with this either.

Comment: @IInspectable: But if I have an associative container, its type tells me the key type, which severely restricts what data I should use as the key.  The compiler doesn't fetch the data automatically, but I never claimed it would.  What it does help with considerably is dumb coding errors (I cast from the `Pointer` member instead of the `hEvent`, or I cast to the type of the data I wanted, instead of the type of the container).  `static_cast` will catch all such nonsense (assuming that you haven't derived every type in your program from `OVERLAPPED` for no apparent reason)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72626/discussion-between-iinspectable-and-ben-voigt).